# how would I get DB info from wp-config.php using file() PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, file

I'm working on a project that involves creating EXTRA tables in the same DB that WP uses.

Before, I was simply just including wp-config.php to get the information, but am now having difficulties using this in parts of the app, that are executed OUTSIDE wordpress.

After posting a question on Wordpress.Stackexchange, one user advised me to use the `file()` function to get the information from `wp-config.php`.

I've loked into the file() funciton but cant understand it well.

Can someone just post an example code to get constant vars like this from a php file:

**wp-config.php:**

```
define('DB_HOST','host');
define('DB_user','user');
define('DB_pass','password');
```

I need to get those variables, to work on the DB side of things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not an elegant solution, but you can use `preg_match` like this if you really need to use a file reading operation:

```
$f = '/path/to/file';
$c = file_get_contents($f);

preg_match('/define.*DB_NAME.*\'(.*)\'/', $c, $m);
$dbname = $m[1];

preg_match('/define.*DB_USER.*\'(.*)\'/', $c, $m);
$dbuser = $m[1];

preg_match('/define.*DB_PASSWORD.*\'(.*)\'/', $c, $m);
$dbpass = $m[1];

preg_match('/define.*DB_HOST.*\'(.*)\'/', $c, $m);
$dbhost = $m[1];

echo $dbname, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbhost
```

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to use php's [`include()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) function in your external file. The code in the WordPress config file will then execute, which will use php's [`define()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php) function, setting those PHP Constant Variables. You can then use them to connect to your database.

Comment: No I cant do that. As I stated in the post, that is what I was previously doing. I'm experiencing many issues with that method now So I cant use it. I need another way. Thanks.