# access WP DB from external php function

Tags: php, database, wordpress

I have a plugin which needs to update the WP database; however the critical function to do this is NOT on a WP page (it's called from a JS function in the background) so it doesn't have the WP Config file already loaded.

At the moment I've hardcoded the DB name/user/pass into the php function page but I'd rather access the WP config.php file and get these details directly in case the site is moved or the DB credentials are changed in future.

My config.php file is in the root of the directory; is there a simple way to access the DB credentials held there?

Comment: Or something like the accepted answer over here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9011432

Answer (score 0):

You can with a JS file, do an AJAX function that calls a PHP file that can retrieve the information from wp-config.php

In your php File

```
echo DB_NAME
echo DB_USER
echo DB_PASSWORD
echo DB_HOST
```